# Apple developer program on older MacOS version

Tags: macos, developer-program

I am hoping to code sign and notarize some software I made, so that people can install it on Mac without hassle. To do this, it appears I need to enroll with the "Apple Developer Program" (as an individual), and download Apple Developer, which requires MacOS 12 or later. Is it possible to code sign and notarize the app on an older MacOS version (in this case, MacOS 11)?